# Flutter get document from collection without knowing its ID but knowing filed name

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to get only one document from the collection.
I have Collection named cards, in this collection I've created Documents with Auto ID, each Document have field `Name`. In one of the documents fild `Name = Horse`. 
How can I retrive this document and all the fields related to it?

The problem that I've faced is that all of the documentation relay on listviews. In my case I don't have a need and use of listview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
final colRef = Firestore.instance.collection("your_path");
final snapshot = await colRef.where("Name", isEqualTo: "Horse").limit(1).getDocuments();
final docSnapshot = snapshot.documents[0];
```